# Why isn't the Flask public server receiving requests?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to set up a server on a windows 10 machine, using Python and Flask, but it is not responding to external requests.

This is my `server.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hi there"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

When running, it says:

```
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://195.XX.XXX.XXX:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Indeed, if I try to access it from that machine, using `127.0.0.1:5000` or `195.XX.XXX.XXX:5000`, it works correctly.

However, when trying to access it from another machine, (using Chrome if that can be an issue), it just loads indefinitely, then says no data received, `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

What is wrong with this? I've followed steps on the documentation so I don't get what could be wrong.

I also disabled firewall entirely on the windows 10 machine.

Comment: Is the other machine in the same network? Do you expose correct port to the network?

Comment: The other machine is on another network.

Comment: Do you have the network set in such a way that you can route to the original machine then?

Comment: @matszwecja The machine was on a remote cloud server, it appears that there was indeed a server level network setup, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

How you're running matters. If it's via

```
python server.py
```

then the `app.run()` will execute, and the server will bind to 0.0.0.0

But if you're running via some variant of

```
FLASK_APP=server.py flask run
```

then `app.run()` won't execute, and the server will bind to 127.0.0.1

In that case, adding `--host=0.0.0.0` should fix things (unless you're having a firewall issue).

Comment: Actually it wouldn't matter here, because 1. I added `--host=0.0.0.0` 2. From the logs I provided it does say it's running on all addresses.